Dropbar levers compatible with Tektro T275 hydro brakes
I bought a Riverside 520 from decathlon. It has a flat bar on it as stock, but I want to buy a drop bar and use STI gear levers. The bike currently has Tektro T275 hydraulic brakes. Are there Sram or Shimano drop bar levers compatible with them?
More specifically, can I use the Shimano GRX ST-RX820 drop bar lever with the existing Tektro T275 hydraulic brake? As far as I know they both use mineral oil, will there be a problem?

The calipers are among the least expensive components (you can get MT200, that are compatible and comparable to the Tektro for 15€), and the ones supplied with the bike are entry level. If your concern is cost, my recommendation would be to wait a few months that CUES drop bar arrives on the market. It's not very consistent to put high-end racing components on touring bike.

Generally, flat bar to drop bar conversions are quite expensive and often not worth it. There was a time when a V brake flat bar bike could be converted to a drop bar bike, by buying a drop bar, bar-end shifters and V brake drop bar levers from Tektro or Dia Compe, very cheaply. That time is over now.
One difficulty is pull ratio of rear derailleur. The current "road" Shimano pull ratio is the same for 10 and 11 speed, because 10-speed Tiagra uses the 11-speed "road" pull ratio. As far as I know, all hydraulic STI shifters must be paired with a rear derailleur for the 11-speed "road" pull ratio, with options for number of sprockets being 10 and 11.
Another difficulty is the hydraulic brakes. Different makers use different fluids, Shimano using mineral oil, so a Shimano lever should be paired with Shimano brakes.
Tektro brakes seem to use mineral oil as well, so there's a possibility you won't immediately ruin the system by fluid incompatibility. However, there's also a chance that piston area with Tektro and Shimano differs, and if this is the case, your brakes won't work well. Also I'm not sure if the Shimano hoses are compatible with Tektro hoses.
You have to be prepared to change all of this:

Rear derailleur (for 11-speed "road" compatibility)
Gear inner and outer cables (since it's likely the old length is not good)
Shifters
Brake calipers (since generally hydraulic brakes from different manufacturers aren't compatible)
All brake hoses
Stem (since drop bar conversion is so big that there's 99% chance the stem length is no longer good)
And obviously, the handlebar

And even then, there's a risk you won't find a stem length that makes the frame geometry good.
Fortunately, hydraulic brake calipers are far cheaper than the STI levers.

Note that the Shimano 12-speed road/gravel seem to use the same pull ratio as 11-speed groupset. If the bike of the OP is the 520 Touring, the RD-RX822-SGS is the only current derailleur that could work with a 11-speed brifter and handle the cassette (11/48, 11-speed). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEEe0hIMpf0

Barend shifters are still available and Tektro/TRP make non-brifter hydraulic levers for drop bars
